# Inserting Swift Code Snippets from Terminal to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, terminal, code-snippets

I'm trying to automate some aspects of the iOS app development process. In this regard, I want to try and insert code into the Xcode project.

I have created snippets but am not sure how I could insert them into an existing project / swift file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is this different then copy-paste?

Comment: I'm trying to do this from the command line and copy-pasting will need me to do two things: 
1. Open and close the files each time
2. Insert code at varying places depending on the need. 

This might be a challenge when the inputs are variable.